# Proving a set $C$ to be closed in a topology (A question related to subspace topology)

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

This particular question is part of an assignment given to me in Topology .

> Let $A$ be a closed subset of a topological space $(X,T)$ and let $C$ be closed subset of $(X,T_A)$. Prove that $C$ is closed in $(X,T)$.

> attempt: As $C$ is closed in $(X,T_A)$ so $C=A\cap D$ , for some $D$ which is closed in $X$. Now $C$ is intersection of $D$ (which is closed in $X$) with some set. So, $C$ must be closed in $X$.

Is this proof correct ?

If not then kindly tell a correct proof.

Comment: You should state correctly that $C$ is the intersection of **two** closed subsets of $X$.

Comment: What is $(X, T_A)$?  Did you mean $(A,T_A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with **some** set, but it's *essential* that $C=A \cap D$ is the intersection of  *closed sets* so is closed.

Yes, it's straight from the definitions and as simple as that.